# While running this code java.lang.nullpointerexception occured and force close the application

Tags: android

---

```
package com.example.minorproject;



import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUp extends Activity
 {

    Intent i=null;
    boolean flag=false;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    EditText tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        EditText tv1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText tv2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText tv3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
        EditText tv4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        EditText tv5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.blood_group);
        EditText tv6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("Create table if not exists BloodDonor(name varchar,email varchar,mobile_no int,address varchar,blood_group varchar,password varchar)");

    }

    public void action(View v)
    {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.login:
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 500);
        break;

    case R.id.sign_up:
        String name=tv1.getText().toString();
        String email=tv2.getText().toString();
        String mobile=tv3.getText().toString();
        String address=tv4.getText().toString();
        String bloodgroup=tv5.getText().toString();
        String password=tv6.getText().toString();

        if(name==null||name==""||name.length()<3)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Name.");
        }

        else if(email==null||email==""||email.length()<10)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Email id.");
        }
        else if(mobile==null||mobile==""||mobile.length()<10)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
        }
        else if(address==null||address==""||address.length()<5)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct address.");
        }
        else if(bloodgroup==null||bloodgroup==""||bloodgroup=="A+ve"||bloodgroup=="A+VE"||bloodgroup=="B+VE"
                ||bloodgroup=="B+ve"||bloodgroup=="AB+ve"||bloodgroup=="AB+VE"||bloodgroup=="O+ve"
                ||bloodgroup=="O+VE"||bloodgroup=="A-ve"||bloodgroup=="A-VE"||bloodgroup=="B-VE"
                ||bloodgroup=="B-ve"||bloodgroup=="AB-ve"||bloodgroup=="AB-VE"||bloodgroup=="O-ve"
                ||bloodgroup=="O-VE")
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct blood group.");
        }
        else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
        {
            show("Please Enter Strong Password.");
        }
        else
        {   
            db.execSQL("insert into login values('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+mobile+"','"+address+"','"+bloodgroup+"','"+password+"''nothing')");
            i=new Intent(this,Home.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 500);

            db.close();
            finish();
        }
        break;
    }

}   


public void show(String str){

    Toast.makeText(this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}   



}
```

here is my logcat

07-03 07:05:55.780: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 7% free 2631K/2820K, paused 129ms, total 169ms

07-03 07:05:55.819: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.147MB for 1536016-byte allocation

07-03 07:05:56.039: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 4128K/4324K, paused 194ms, total 194ms

07-03 07:05:58.410: D/gralloc_goldfish(795): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

07-03 07:06:12.809: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 4% free 4242K/4376K, paused 128ms, total 130ms

07-03 07:06:12.859: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.720MB for 1536016-byte allocation

07-03 07:06:13.109: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 5741K/5880K, paused 245ms, total 245ms

07-03 07:06:16.108: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

07-03 07:06:22.759: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

07-03 07:06:54.290: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

07-03 07:07:03.780: D/AndroidRuntime(795): Shutting down VM

07-03 07:07:03.789: W/dalvikvm(795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.example.minorproject.SignUp.action(SignUp.java:47)

07-03 07:07:03.869: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 14 more

07-03 07:07:10.749: D/dalvikvm(828): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 7% free 2631K/2824K, paused 38ms, total 41ms

07-03 07:07:10.759: I/dalvikvm-heap(828): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.147MB for 1536016-byte allocation

07-03 07:07:10.879: D/dalvikvm(828): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 4129K/4328K, paused 113ms, total 113ms

07-03 07:07:11.489: I/Choreographer(828): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

07-03 07:07:11.519: D/gralloc_goldfish(828): Emulator without GPU emulation detected

Comment: plz post ur crash log

Comment: Could you state what you are trying to do and include the logcat of the exception

Comment: i am trying to enter the data in sqlite database.but whenever i enter data and try to click to send to database then above error occurs and cause application to forceclose @RichardTingle

Answer (score 1):

You have created `EditText` object local to `onCreate()` instead assigning that object to class level object, try this,

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        tv1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        tv3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
        tv4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        tv5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.blood_group);
        tv6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("Create table if not exists BloodDonor(name varchar,email varchar,mobile_no int,address varchar,blood_group varchar,password varchar)");

    }
```

Comment: Indeed, this is [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)